# C# A Linq Lamda query to form a view model list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `ViewModel`

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public ProductModel Product { get; set; }
    public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

- I query the database and fetch a Dataset which has one table say `Table[0]` that has- many rows- a list of details of all the members of my ViewModel (i.e. Product,ProductVersion,User)

My db query is as below

```
SELECT productName,
       productID,
       productPrice,
       ...
       PRODUCTVerion, 
       UserName,
       UserID,
       UserEmail
  FROM Product,
       ProductVersionCtrl,
       User
  ...
```

- The return type of my method is
  IEnumnerable of ProductViewModel
  <>
- **My Requirement** I need a lamda linq query that would frame\form the object IEnumnerable
  of ProductViewModel 
  return type is given below

> `IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>`

**What I have tried**

I have idea to place simple data which belongs to one complex object liek

```
IEnumerable<DealerModel> list = dsData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(p =>
            new DealerModel()
            {
                DealerID = int.Parse(p["DealerID"].ToString()),
                DealerName = p["DealerName"].ToString(),
                DealerContactNo = p["DealerContactNo"].ToString(),
                DealerEmailID = p["DealerEmailID"].ToString(),
                DealerPassword = "******",
                IsActive = int.Parse(p["IsActive"].ToString())
            });
```

But I am not able to place different object within the ViewModel

Comment: Welcome to SO jeAntoni. Instead of just telling us what your "requirement" is, could you also add some code showing what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it , The below worked for me.

```
IEnumerable<ProductBuyViewModel> productBuyList = dsData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(p =>
                 new ProductBuyViewModel()
                 {
                      ProductBuy = {ProductName = p["productName "],ProductPrice =p["ProductPrice ...]},
                      ProductVesrion =p["ProductVesrion "],
                      User         = {UserName =...}
                 });
```